# Flutter layout: placing a widget only half in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to layout two widgets in a Row where the first widget is simply centered (more or less) but the second widget should be rendered only half. I made this simple illustration with two containers (`C1` and `C2`) where I want `C2` to be displayed on the right but only the left part of it should be visible. The right part should be hidden. I experimented a lot with `ClipRect` and `OverFlowBox` but I seem to not be able to find a working solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the positioned widget. In this video, you can check how it works! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ

Comment: Thanks, had it working using`Stack(children: [Child1, Positioned(left: -230, child: Child2)])`